# Ipython notebook will not open

Tags: jupyter-notebook

When I try to open ipython notebook from within linux ubuntu vm the web browser pops up but does not connect and I get the following repeating error message:

```
KeyError: 3
ERROR:root:Esception in I/O handler for fd 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 330, in start
    self._handlers(fd, events)
```

Any thoughts?

Thank you

Rob

Comment: How did you install iPython Notebook? You should use an installer like Anaconda which avoids these kind of errors and you have all standard libraries in the package. I had all kinds of error message on an older mac, but when I used Anaconda, my problems were solved.

Answer (score 0):

I received this same error. In my case, I had an older version of pyzmq that did not automatically get upgraded when I upgraded ipython notebook. Try doing a pip install pyzmq --upgrade.